# KL divergence between normal and skewnormal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, information-theory, kullback-leibler, skew-normal-distribution

I am trying to find an analytical expression for the KL divergence between a normal distribution and a skewnormal distribution. In this paper https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/14/9/1606 they derive the KL-divergence between two skewnormal distributions  $\boldsymbol{X}\sim SN(\boldsymbol{\xi}_1, \boldsymbol{\Omega}_1, \boldsymbol{\eta}_1)$ and $\boldsymbol{Y}\sim SN(\boldsymbol{\xi}_2, \boldsymbol{\Omega}_2, \boldsymbol{\eta}_2)$ as:

\begin{align}
D_{KL}(\boldsymbol{X}, \boldsymbol{Y}) = D_{KL}(\boldsymbol{X}_0, \boldsymbol{Y}_0) &+ \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}(\boldsymbol{\xi}_1-\boldsymbol{\xi}_2)^\top \boldsymbol{\Omega}_2^{-1} \boldsymbol{\delta}_1 \\&+ \mathbb{E}[\log\{2\Phi(W_{11})\}] -\mathbb{E}[\log\{2\Phi(W_{21})\}],
\end{align}

where $\boldsymbol{X}_0\sim N(\boldsymbol{\xi}_1, \boldsymbol{\Omega}_1)$, $\boldsymbol{Y}_0\sim N(\boldsymbol{\xi}_1, \boldsymbol{\Omega}_1$), $\Phi$ is the univariate $N(0,1)$ cdf, $\boldsymbol{\delta}_j = \boldsymbol{\Omega}_j \boldsymbol{\eta}_j / \sqrt{1+\boldsymbol{\eta}_j^\top \boldsymbol{\Omega}_j \boldsymbol{\eta}_j}$ for $j=1,2$ and

$W_{ij} \sim SN \Big(\boldsymbol{\eta}_i^\top(\boldsymbol{\xi}_j-\boldsymbol{\xi}_i), \boldsymbol{\eta}_i^\top \boldsymbol{\Omega}_j\boldsymbol{\eta}_i, \frac{\boldsymbol{\eta}_i^\top \boldsymbol{\delta}_j}{\sqrt{\boldsymbol{\eta}_i^\top \boldsymbol{\Omega}_j \boldsymbol{\eta}_i-(\boldsymbol{\eta}_i^\top \boldsymbol{\delta}_j)^2}}\Big)$.

So I am trying to find an analytical solution for the special case $\boldsymbol{\eta}_1 = \boldsymbol{0}$. This leads to $\boldsymbol{\delta}_1=0$ and therefore:

$W_{11} \sim N(0, 0)$ and $W_{21} \sim N(\boldsymbol{\eta}_2^\top(\boldsymbol{\xi}_1-\boldsymbol{\xi}_2), \boldsymbol{\eta}_2^\top \boldsymbol{\Omega}_1\boldsymbol{\eta}_2)$.

Consider $x\sim N(0,1)$:

$\mathbb{E}[\log\{2\Phi(x)\}] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})\log(1+erf(x/\sqrt{2}) dx = \log(2) - 1$.

Is there also an analytical solution for $u\sim N(m, s)$:

$\mathbb{E}[\log\{2\Phi(u)\}] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}s} \exp(-\frac{(u-m)^2}{2s^2})\log(1+erf(u/\sqrt{2})) du=?$